# cassandra 'handshaking version with'

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have 2 nodes

```
ip1 node1's ip
ip2 nodes2's ip
```

each node starting but not connecting each other.. For example nodetool status show own node. Not other node

in node1's log:

```
Handshaking version with /ip2
```

in node2's log there are no info or error messages related to node1

no error messages both of them. What causes this problem?

Comment: many things - firewall between, incorrect broadcast address, etc.

Comment: Firewall disabled in digitalocean. 
Broadcast addresses are node’s ip address. 
Node1 broadcast : ip1 node 2’s broadcast: ip2

Comment: node1's config:     listen : ip1, rpc: ip1, broadcast : ip1 ,seeds : "ip1, ip2" , auto_bootstap: false

Comment: node2's config: listen : ip2, rpc: ip2, broadcast : ip2 ,seeds : "ip2, ip1" , auto_bootstap: false

Comment: Have you checked seed address ? you need to put the same seed address on both the nodes.

Comment: yes same seed but different order. like ı said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A node should not normally be in its own seed list; if it is, it will not try to join the existing cluster.  Only the first node in a cluster should be in its own seed list.

Try putting only ip1 in both nodes' seed list and leave ip2 out of the seed list entirely. Also, set `auto_bootstrap: true` on node 2. Shut down the nodes, remove the `/var/lib/cassandra` directory from both nodes, and then start node 1. When node 1 finishes starting up (check for status UN using `nodetool status`), then start node 2. It should now talk to node 1 and join the cluster.