# Problem Starting Cassandra Multinode cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

as title said I've got some problems with adding node in a cassandra cluster.
To be more specific: i have to do a relation in which i take data on how good a Cassandra cluster scales adding various node, in particular i have to launch a little cassandra script that

-load a CSV

-add and remove a entry

-do some queries

-delete the stuffs done and reset the cluster

all on 1 up to 4 clusters and record the time it takes to execute the steps.

Now: i'm on a windows laptop but i managed to start cassandra also in a linux VM, all on a single node following (tell me if i'm spamming too much links) this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1xc1HVsRk0&list=PLalrWAGybpB-L1PGA-NfFu2uiWHEsdscD&index=1

and i've tried without success to add new nodes following thoose:
http://www.learnmodeon.com/cassandra-cluster-setup-for-linux/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3pe8XHzztM&list=PLrwkeifIVAoSSRCeqi8Rfc2smuUadww-Y&index=2&t=0s
https://manthapavankumar.wordpress.com/2015/06/20/configuring-multi-node-cassandra-cluster-on-windows-machine/
https://blog.knoldus.com/running-multinode-cassandra-cluster-on-a-single-machine/
https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849515122/1/ch01lvl1sec11/running-multiple-instances-on-a-single-machine
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHMJrhMtv3c

all not working(cassandra doesn't show other nodes or they tell me to modify file that doesn't exist on my computer like conf/log4j-server.properties)both on linux[mint 19] and windows 10

the version of Cassandra i'm using is 3.11.3 on both (but i think any version should be fine for the target of this project) and the python script works on single node in around 4 minutes total for a 10000+rows csv(tell me if I have to post it)

I'm out of ideas, Thank if you have some.

edit: i can launch only 1 node at time, if i try activate a second ine i get 
VerifyPortsAreAvailable : Found a port already in use. Aborting startup
In D:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.3\bin\cassandra.ps1:98 car:9
+         VerifyPortsAreAvailable
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,VerifyPortsAreAvailable

VerifyPortsAreAvailable :   TCP    127.0.0.1:7000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
In D:\Program Files\apache-cassandra-3.11.3\bin\cassandra.ps1:98 car:9
+         VerifyPortsAreAvailable
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,VerifyPortsAreAvailable

on Windows and

Starting cassandra as root is user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different starting system user.

on Linux

Answer (score 0):

If nodes are starting but they aren't seeing each other, you probably have your seed nodes configured incorrectly in cassandra.yaml. I have already explained the correct way to set up seed nodes on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60765384/1598419).

Regarding log4j-server.properties, it sounds like you are looking at some old documentation. Logging is now configured in logback.xml.

Comment: Do you have a link to a tutorial (video, blog, ppt, ...) or the part of the documentation that tell how to start multiple node on single Notebook?
I tried removing self-seed and nothing changed.

Comment: Running on a single notebook can be tricky because you have port conflicts and the like.  There is a tool called [ccm](https://github.com/riptano/ccm) that can automate this. I don't think it works on Windows though. You will have better luck in general running Cassandra on Linux because that's what everybody else uses and you're less likely to have problems if you go with the crowd. Use a VM if you have to. Another option would be to use [Docker](https://medium.com/@jayarajjg/setting-up-a-cassandra-cluster-on-your-laptop-using-docker-cf09b1bb651e).